# Смена языка на сайте PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Такой вопрос. Необходимо реализовать на сайте смену языка русский-английский. С самой системой я знаком, т.е. заменяем слова на переменные и в зависимости от выбранного языка изменяем значение переменной - это понятно. Но как сделать перевод если значения выводятся из базы в цикле while ?

Например:

```
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT *FROM `names`");
while( $data = $result->fetch_assoc() ) {
    $name = $data['name'];
    echo "$name";
}
```

Все значения поля name в базе на английском языке.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тут все зависит от того, кто и как заполняет базу. Одно дело, если базу заполняет разработчик сайта, и совсем другое дело, если база заполняется пользователями.

Одно из типовых решений - дублировать поля в таблицах с переводом текста на разных языках.
Если в таблице есть поле Title, заполняемое на русском языке, то имеет смысл добавить в эту же таблицу поле TitleEn, куда писать все то же самое, но уже на английском языке (и т.д., для каждого языка свое поле).
Затем в зависимости от выбранного языка при формировании запроса к базе подставляются разные имена полей.

Answer (score 1):

В добавление к написаному reshu добавлю - у себя реализовал для 2 языков добавив к полям индекс (_ru, _eng) . При инициализации страницы проверяем какой язык установлен, присваиваем переменной lang и при запросах к бд получаем такое:

```
"select name."$lang",title."$lang" from pages" => "select name._eng,title_eng from pages"
```

- в запросах в таких случаях лучше не использовать, а перечислять поля которые собираемся выбрать.